# Error deserializing JSON credential Data C# Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, json, google-api, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I'm currently trying to use a service account to access GoogleSheets API - the problem I am having is with my .json file.

Here is my code:

```
    try
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets, SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly }; // Put your scopes here

        var stream = new FileStream("my_application_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
        credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);

        SheetsService service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "myApplication",
        });
        return service;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Create service account myApplicationServiceAccount failed : " + ex.Message);
        throw new Exception("Create ServiceAccount Failed : ", ex);
    }
```

This kicks off my error which reads:

```
Create service account myApplicationServiceAccount failed : Error deserializing JSON credential data.
```

But everything I can find online says that what I have above should work.

Is there something more I have to do with this .json file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out - because I'm supporting older versions of .NET (4 and below) I am using a slightly older version of the Google Sheets API.

But the Newtonsoft.JSON package was out of date as well. Updated that and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You may check on this [related GitHub thread](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/684). Given workaround is:

```
install-package Microsoft.Bcl.Build
install-package Microsoft.Bcl.Async
install-package Microsoft.Net.Http
```

Also, you can follow this [tutorial](http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c) about JSON Serialization/Deserialization in C# and see if you miss something.

Comment: Those have been installed via Nu-Get; is there somewhere else I need to include those?

Answer (score 0):

try deserializing the object using `Newtonsoft.Json` library 
`http://www.newtonsoft.com/json`

`return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SheetsService>(service);`

but the error is in deserializing JSON credential data, so this might be helpful : 
`credential = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<credential.CreateScoped>(scopes);`

Comment: It says 'Cannot convert from 'Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService' to 'string'.

I feel like maybe I need to focus the deserialization on the my_application_secret.json file instead?

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService>(scopes);`

Comment: That gives me the same result unfortunately. Also your update above regarding the credential doesn't work either - <credential.CreateScoped> gives me an error: 'credential is a variable but is used like a type'